# How can I set an entry title automatically, based on a related entry?

Tags: entries, titles

If a booking channel contains two Entries fields (one related to a single User, one related to a single 'Event'), how can I get the booking entry title to be set automatically to the following syntax:

"Event Date - Username"

I've set up the entry to not show the title field, but my syntax is wrong. I'm using:

```
{{eventBooking.title}} - {{userBooking.username}}
```

but all I'm getting is "-", so it's obviously not recognising the fields. Is this possible?

Comment: Are you actually trying to set an entry's title or are you trying to display a title on a page as a combination of those values?

Comment: I was trying to set the entry's title based on those values when the entry gets created. This has been answered by Ben now below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this is in regards to the `Title Format` feature, so just to be explicit in what I'm referring to, Craft Documentation calls this a [Dynamic Entry Title](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/sections-and-entries#dynamic-entry-titles).

The syntax you are looking for can take two forms:

**1) Long form object syntax**

Just as on the front end your `entry` is available via the `{{ entry }}` variable, within your Title pattern on the back end, the current entry is available via the `{{ object }}` variable.

So I believe the following should work, assuming you are using the actual field names:

```
{{ object.eventBooking.one().title }} - {{ object.userBooking.one().username }}
```

You need to use the `one()` method here because Relations fields return an array by default. Since you need to output your content directly, you need to make sure you are accessing the `title` and `username` properties via the Model they are associated with in that array.  If your fields are required, you can safely assume that the first item will exist in the array.

**2) Short hand syntax**

If what you are doing is simple, Craft gives you the option to make the syntax a bit easier and omit the `object` variable.  So the above could also be written with single curly braces as such:

```
{eventBooking.one().title} - {userBooking.one().username}
```

Comment: That shorthand syntax works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: This no longer seems to be working, as of Craft 4. Instead, `{fieldName.one().title}` is working for me.

Comment: Good note. That changed a while ago. I updated the answer to reflect the .one() syntax.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on an entry page have you tried:

{{ entry.eventBooking.title }}

Because at the moment it doesn't look like your telling craft to look at the eventBooking handle on the entry but the title on a eventBooking variable

Comment: I understand what you're saying and it makes sense, but no I still just get "-"

Comment: You may need to specify the .first() related entry. {{entry.eventBooking.first().title}}