# I managed to make an entry type that won't let me create any entries. How can I fix it?

Tags: entries, admin, entry-type, entries-field

I managed to make an entry type that won't let me create any entries.

The site is for a rock band, and the entry type in question is called "Shows". It contains five fields:

- Venue
- Lineup
- Date
- Time
- Body

Date and Time are Date/Time fields, Lineup and Body are standard text fields. Venue is the field that I think is causing the trouble.

Venue is an Entries field that lets you select one from several venues, which are entries in a separate section (a Structure) called Venues.

When I enter data for a show, I'm able to select from the list of venues. When I try to save the Show, however, I get an error:

> Recoverable error: Object of class Craft\ElementCriteriaModel could not be converted to string.

The most meaningful looking highlighted line in the debug output is:

```
echo $this->getAttribute((isset($context["object"]) ? $context["object"] : $this->getContext($context, "object")), "venue", array());
```

All these pages are in the admin section, not in my templates, thus they are pages I can't edit, so I don't know what I can do to fix this error. Is it possible that I have created an entry type that Craft can't handle? There doesn't seem to be anything that unusual about the Venue entry type.

Have I done something obviously wrong? If not, how do I debug this?

Comment: Are you on the latest version of Craft? Try manually replacing your `craft/app` folder to ensure you don't have any missing or corrupt files.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but manually replacing the app folder with the latest version (and clearing cache and reloading) made no change.

Comment: The file causing the error is in `/craft/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/`. Can I force Craft to recompile templates somehow?

Comment: You can safely delete the entire contents of the `runtime` folder. Not sure if that'll make a difference though.

Comment: If I click "Show the Title field" on, the admin page operates correctly. I really didn't want it on but I guess I'm formatting the Craft-generated title fields incorrectly, and that's where the error is really coming from.

Comment: Yup, that's the issue. Your dynamic title format is causing problems.

Comment: When you figure out the specific formatting issue, go ahead and post that below as an official answer! :)

Comment: What's the pattern you're using? Maybe we can identify the issue.

Comment: Yes, and it's beyond my pay grade to figure it out.

I started with `{venue}`, per the advice " You can include tags that output entry properties, such as {myCustomField}." I also tried `{venue.title}`. (The venue name is not an actual field in my entry type, it gets its value from the title.)

Per https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1689/how-can-i-set-an-entry-title-automatically-based-on-a-related-entry ,
I also tried `{{ object.shows.venue }}` and `{{ object.shows.first().venue }}`, which didn't work. I was not getting the debug page, just a message "Couldn't save entry."

Comment: Also `{{ entry.venue.title }}`. Thanks for all the help, by the way.

Comment: Which one are you using when you get that error?  You probably just need `entry.venue.first().title` (assuming you want to use the first selected venue for the title).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to have a [dynamic title](https://craftcms.com/docs/sections-and-entries#dynamic-entry-titles) for that section, based on an Entries field (Venue). Working out the nuances in this situation can be a little tricky, but I think this would do the trick for you:

```
{{ object.venue.first().title ?? '(no venue)' }}
```

Let's break down what's happening here...

In this use-case, `object` is your Entry. Which means that `object.venue` is your Venue field (which happens to be an Entries field type).

Since Venue is an Entries field type, that means it's going to return an [Element Criteria Model](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel). When dealing with an ECM, you need to append something like `find()` (get all) or `first()` (get one) to end up with an actual, useful result.

Once we've established that you only need a single Entry (`object.venue.first()`), let's go ahead and grab the title of that Entry (`object.venue.first().title`). The good news... that can all be chained together! The bad news... it'll throw an error if the Venue field is left empty.

Which is where `?? '(no venue)'` comes in. The double question mark is called a [null-coalescing operator](https://straightupcraft.com/events/twigs-null-coalescing-operator). It provides a graceful fallback, suppressing error messages and allowing you to provide a safe alternative.

Put it all together, and you'll have a nice, *safe* dynamic title.