# How to Auto-generate a Title based on a multiple entries titles? (using a Entries field type)

Tags: entries, fieldtypes, titles, format, auto-generate

I have two sections *(both Channel type)*:

- Releases
- Movies

**Releases** have one **Entries field type**, the source is **Movies**

So, I want Auto-generate a **Release** title from **Movies**, like this: **Titanic, Avatar, Toy Story**

This works `{ movies.one().title }` as a **Title Format** on the **Releases** Settings but display just the first movie: **Titanic**, the question is how can load all the entries titles? to get **Titanic, Avatar, Toy Story** as a title

I do a research and I get this: [How can I set an entry title automatically, based on a related entry?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1689/how-can-i-set-an-entry-title-automatically-based-on-a-related-entry) but again that display only the first entry title.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this can be done in the shorthand syntax, but you can do this using Twig for the dynamic title format. The key is to use [map](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/map.html) to turn an array of entries into an array of titles and then [join](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/join.html) them. Something like this should work:

```
{{ object.movies.all()|map(movie => movie.title)|join(', ')|default('No movies selected') }}
```

Also note the [default](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/default.html) filter, which is a nice fallback in case no entries are selected in your `movie` field.

Comment: It works!, the field is required but yes the default is a nice fallback.